# Knight's tour on 4x4 and 8x8 chess board

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path, chessboard, knight-tours

Prove that:-

$\bullet$A (open or closed) knight's tour is not possible on a $4\times4$ chess board.

$\bullet$A (open or closed) knight's tour exists on a $8\times8$ chess board.

I want a constructive proof for $8\times8$ board, not just a possible solution.
I know that the question boils down to finding a hamiltonian path in Knights' graph.

Comment: A concrete solution _is_ a constructive proof that a solution exists -- the best and most constructive imaginable.

Comment: @HenningMakholm While I agree with you, I think he wants some insight into why it exists for some dimensions and not for others. What works in $8\times 8$ that fails in $4\times 4$?

Comment: [Here is a paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2690649) (Schwenk, Math. Mag.  64(5) 325-332, 1991) that seems to solve the general problem. Unfortunately it's behind a spamwall.

Comment: Have a look at the [Wikipedia article on the knight's tour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour). For the general rectangular case, see the article [Which Rectangular Chessboards Have a Knight's Tour?](http://bit.ly/2eXyNwB) by Schwenk.

Comment: [Linked](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2010903/a-closed-knights-tour-does-not-exist-on-some-chessboards).